# NSMutableAray RemoveObject: Not Working As Expected

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have recently begun working with cocoa and Objective-C, although I am not new to software concepts, and I have come across some curious and unanticipated behavior in the NSMutableArray Class.

First, I create and populate a 'NSMutableArray' Object, with my custom objects of Class 'CustomClass' which works fine. Then I proceed to attempt to delete one of the objects, and I do not get the results I want.

```
// NSMutableArray *Array is already initialized and loaded with 5 CustomClass Objects
//   stored in variables 'CustomClassObject1' through 'CustomClassObject5'. 
[Array removeObject:CustomClassObject4];
```

Rather than this code simply removing the fourth entry, as I want it to, it sets the fourth entry to 'nil' (That is, (id) 0x00000000), and, more confusingly, *deletes the last entry in the array*.

In my understanding, this is not supposed to happen - all that should happen is the fourth entry should be removed, replaced by the fifth. Instead, I now have an array with three objects and one nil!

I've also tried

```
int position = [Array indexOfObject:CustomClassObject4];
[Array removeObjectatIndex:position];
```

Only to obtain the same result. Does anyone know why this is happening?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Code:

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray array];

CustomClass *CustomClassObject1 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject2 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject3 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject4 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject5 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];

[Array AddObject:CustomClassObject1];
[Array AddObject:CustomClassObject2];
[Array AddObject:CustomClassObject3];
[Array AddObject:CustomClassObject4];
[Array AddObject:CustomClassObject5];
```

Output at this point:

```
_Array = (NSMutableArray *) 0x0885c2c0 @ "5 Objects"
[0] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c5f0
[1] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c630
[2] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c690
[3] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c6f0
[4] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c730
```

Then:

```
[Array removeObject:CustomClassObject4];
```

Output at this point:

```
_Array = (NSMutableArray *) 0x0885c2c0 @ "4 Objects"
[0] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c5f0
[1] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c630
[2] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c690
[3] = (id) 0x00000000
```

If instead I delete the 3rd object,

```
[Array removeObject:CustomClassObject3];
```

Output is then:

```
_Array = (NSMutableArray *) 0x0885c2c0 @ "4 Objects"
[0] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c5f0
[1] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c630
[2] = (id) 0x00000000
[3] = (CustomClass *) 0x0885c6f0
```

Comment: after setting objects to array print all values of array and check last row exist or not.May be last class not initialised

Comment: Try to post whole code here so that we can understand how you have initialized it and what is inside the array after inserting objects.Show output by printing array after setting objects in it.

Comment: Are you sure `NSMutableArray` is exhibiting this behaviour? Post the code you use to to get these unexpected results.

Comment: NSArray cannot store nil.  How are you determining that the fourth element of the array is nil?

Comment: I assume that is the nil object. I may be mistaken on that one. Code Posted

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  How are you determining the state of these variables?  What commands are you executing in the debugger?

Comment: now clarified what you have faced, good

Comment: try initialization of array as NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:5];  OR NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: Do me a favour and try to find the object in the array, instead of using the pointer you have to delete it. 
After you have found it through the array, see what happens when you delete it.
Also, are you sure you are using arc? Finally, are you enumerating and deleting, or just deleting as we see your code above???

Comment: CodaFi: I've set breakpoints and am looking at the data it shows in the bottom pop-up window. Hercules: Same result. Alex: Same result. Yes. I'm just deleting... I'm not familiar with enumerating. What is its purpose?

Comment: Yes, but are you `po`'ing the objects themselves, or the array?

Comment: CodaFi: sorry, am not familiar with the terminology: 'po'ing'? I am looking at the array; the objects themselves dont seem to change.

Comment: Here, I think I know what's wrong.  See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It all boils down to how ARC handles local variables.  For a moment, I'm going to pretend to turn off ARC to show you how your code is memory managed for illustration purposes:

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray array];

//All of these are initialized with a +1 retain count
CustomClass *CustomClassObject1 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject2 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject3 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject4 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
CustomClass *CustomClassObject5 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];

//The array retains what gets put into it, meaning it owns these variables
//And gives them a total reference count of +2
[Array AddObject:[CustomClassObject1 retain]];
[Array AddObject:[CustomClassObject2 retain]];
[Array AddObject:[CustomClassObject3 retain]];
[Array AddObject:[CustomClassObject4 retain]];
[Array AddObject:[CustomClassObject5 retain]];

//The compiler inserts a release for each of those objects because you
//Don't reference them before the method's scope ends.  The array still owns
//them, so they all have a total reference count of +1 at this point.
[CustomClassObject1 release];
[CustomClassObject2 release];
[CustomClassObject3 release];
[CustomClassObject4 release];
[CustomClassObject5 release];
```

When you remove an object, the array decrements it's reference count, so when you remove `CustomClassObject4`, it's reference count drops to a big fat 0, and it gets deallocated.  That's the nil you're seeing.  To fix it, retain those objects outside of the scope of that method in either strong iVars, properties, or a global.

Comment: memory management is another issue , that caused error many times,because callling objects that have released already quits the app.+1 for this buddy

Comment: Thanks CodaFi, that sounds like it makes sense, but I added CustomClassObject4 to *another* array before I removed it, and the same result happened.

Comment: Then the array went out of scope and was released

Comment: I added the object to the second array on the line previous to removing it from the first array. Is this still out of scope? If so, can I just make a strong variable in the same scope and store it there?

Comment: No.  You need to store it in something that won't disappear when the method's stack frame gets crushed.  Store it in an iVar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try something simpler:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
[array addObject: [[CustomClass alloc] init] ];
// repeat for as many times you want.

// Fast enumerate the loop and get an output - You class will need to provide method id
for ( CustomClass * c in array ) NSLog( @"Class id: %@", [c id] );

// Then try to delete any random object.
[array removeObjectAtIndex: [array indexOfObject: object] ];

// And repeat the enumeration
for ( CustomClass * c in array ) NSLog( @"Class id: %@", [c id] );
```

Can you please try this and tell us what happened?
Also, add breakpoints at each add and delete operation.

Make sure you have arc enabled, and that your code is within the autorelease pool!

Comment: This code worked as expected, after the removeObjectAtIndex is called. Thanks, I can use this as a starting point. Really I just wanted to know if anyone had seen that before, thanks for your help all.